# Virtual directory problem in IIS for asp.net web application

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

My asp.net web application works fine locally and when I deploy it as the default web site on my test server.  So for example, when I type http:// 10.10.10.100 it works fine.

I created a virtual directory called "Test" under my "Default Web Site".

When I type http://10.10.10.100/Test it loads correctly to my log-in page, however when I log-in and click on a link it goes back to my log-in page and the url goes back referencing http://10.10.10.100 instead of http://10.10.10.100/Test/Default.aspx, for example.

My goal here is to run my application from the virtual directory and not as the default, but I don't want to change my code to a hard coded path since then it won't work anywhere else.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: This is way too vague. There are so many unanswered questions. Are you following a template of any sort? Any books that you're using for reference? This appears to be your first asp.net app, is that right?

Comment: I am new to web development and to these forums. Let me know how I can clarify things.

Comment: Well then welcome @user438331 <- using this syntax lets the system alert users to new responses, as far as I know it can be anywhere within a comment, but I'm not sure. I usually stick mine at the front. Next, you'll want to read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (hey, do you want to be answered quickly?) and lastly, if this guy http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet answers, listen. Don't argue.

Answer (score 0):

You have left a few unanswered questions, but some things to check:

1. Which links are you using?  In other words, are they plain HTML links (<a href=""> links), ASP.NET links (<asp:HyperLink>), LinkButtons (<asp:LinkButton>), etc.?
2. How are you specifying the URL in those links?  ASP.NET has a "shortcut" for root directory of the website if you use the tilde (~) character.  So, to link to a page on your site called "MyPage.aspx", you might use "~/MyPage.aspx".

Comment: originally, the application was using <a href="">. However, I changed them to ASPxHyperLink. <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="Campaigns" runat="server" Text="Campaigns" Font-Bold ="true" Width="92px" Cursor="pointer" NavigateUrl ="~/Campaign/Default.aspx"/></li>

Comment: My application seems to be working now after being published to my target server. I appreciate your help.